# Error "Invalid Qualifier" with unknown cause

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba code and i was wondering if anyone could help me indentify the invalid quailfier in this code. the code isnt the best or neatest but this was supposed to be a quick 1 hour project that has now taken all morning.

If i did this right it should go through the coloumns with the variants recorded population precentage and remove the base pair information to leave only the number and then store the base pair information in the next column.

```
Sub PopPrecentnumonlyinator()
    Dim base_pair As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim iii As Integer
    Dim iv As Integer
    Dim vi As Integer
    Dim vii As Integer
    Dim viii As Integer
    Dim hrange As String
    
    base_pair = ""
    hrange = ""
        
    For i = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "H" & i
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "A" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("I" & i).Value = "A"
        End If
    Next i
    
            For ii = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "H" & ii
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "C" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("I" & ii).Value = "C"
        End If
    Next ii
    
            For iii = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "H" & iii
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "T" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("I" & iii).Value = "T"
        End If
    Next iii
    
            For iv = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "H" & iv
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "G" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("I" & iv).Value = "G"
        End If
    Next iv
    
         For v = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "K" & v
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "A" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("L" & v).Value = "A"
        End If
    Next v
    
            For vi = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "K" & vi
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "C" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("L" & vi).Value = "C"
        End If
    Next vi
    
            For vii = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "K" & vii
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "T" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("L" & vii).Value = "T"
        End If
    Next vii
    
            For viii = 2 To 12069
        hrange = "K" & viii
        If Left(hrange.Value, 1) = "G" Then
            hrange.Value = Right(hrange.Value, Len(hrange.Value) - 2)
            Range("L" & viii).Value = "G"
        End If
    Next viii
End Sub
```

The goal was to remove a piece of info from one cell and then place the info in the enxt column over.

Comment: `hrange` is a `String`. You can't call `.Value` on a string. `Dim hrange As Range`, then `Set hrange = Range("H" & i)`.